# Calculating a tangent line to an implicitly given function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ be continuously differentiable and let $p\in\mathbb{R}^3 $ for which $F(p)=0$ . 
Assume $rank DF|_p =2 $ and denote by $E$ the set $E=(x\in \mathbb{R}^3 | F(x)=0) $ .

Implicit function theorem guarantees the existence of a neighberhood $B$ of $p$ such that $B\cap E$ is a smooth curve (/path).

If $DF|_p =  \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & -1 & 2  \\[0.3em]         
       3 & 0  & 1 
     \end{bmatrix} $ 
how can one calculate a tangent line to the curve $B\cap E$ I just mentioned ? (at $p$ obviously).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\gamma(t)$ is some differentiable parametrization of $E \cap B$, then $F(\gamma(t)) = 0$.  By the chain rule, $0 = \frac{d}{dt}F(\gamma(t)) = DF(\gamma'(t)) = 0$ for all $t$ for which $\gamma(t)$ is defined.  Thus $\gamma'(t) \in \ker DF$.  This implies that $\gamma'(t)$ can, up to a scalar multiple, be had by solving the linear system $DF(\gamma'(t)) = 0$.    With $DF_p$ as given, we see that with $\gamma'(t_0) = (u, v, w)^T$, where $\gamma(t_0) = p$, we have

$u - v +2w = 0, \tag{1}$

and

$3u + w = 0;  \tag{2}$

the solution to (1), (2) is the one-dimensional family of vectors  $w(-1/3, 5/3, 1)^T$; this in turn implies the requisite tangent line is $\hat p + w(-1/3, 5/3, 1)$, where we take $\hat p$ to mean the ordered triple $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$ of coordinates of the point $p$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: A few questions, if I may:
1.  I guess that in your first line, you mean "parameterization of $B\cap E$ , right?2. Can you explain your use of the chain rule by which you arrived to $DF(\gamma '(t))=0$?
I think I understood the rest. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ criticism 46:  of course your right about $E \cap B$; so edited.  I also added a minor edit in re. the chain rule business, does that clarify things?  If not, let me know *via* comment and I'll be glad to further explain.  Regards.

Comment: @criticism 46:  chain rule shows that $\frac{d}{dt}F_k(\gamma) = \sum \frac{\partial F_k}{\partial x_j}\gamma_j'$etc.  Need more? Let me know!

Comment: @ criricism:  please check the comments for more info.  I may have mispelled your handle and my remarks might not have reached you!

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks a lot ! (I hope it will be ok if I'll reply here again if I'll have any more questions about this. Thanks)

Comment: @ criticism:  yes, of course!